# shdocvw.InternetExplorer NewWindow3/2. Cannot use my own Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code in a Visual Studio 2010 WPF program.  I am automating Internet Explorer and not a webbrowser on a form.

```
Private Sub ie_NewWindow3(ByRef ppDisp As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger, ByVal bstrUrlContext As String, ByVal bstrUrl As String) Handles ie.NewWindow3
    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie.RegisterAsBrowser = True
    ppDisp = ie.Application
    ie.Visible = True
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

When the event fires I get my new Internet Explorer but it has a ready state of Uninitilized and just sits there doing nothing and no events seem to fire.  Can any body help.

I have tried it on for example this simple website [Simple Popup example](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_open_link_in_new_window.cfm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah it is simple.  When it is internet explorer you don't need to cancel.  The Window you provide is the only window made.